# update the ASP.NET site/WebApp without affecting user

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

we have large webApp with +2K online user at same time.
sometime we need update part of webapplication(update dll or UI) 
Is it possible to update the ASP.NET site/WebApp without affecting user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only View(CSHTML) razor View chnages, then you can copy them without stopping App pool or IIS.

If you logic chnages in controller classes or in *.CS/*.vb files, then you have to copy the DLL in that case you can make use of App_offline.cshtml page to prompt users as site is offline and copy DLL immediately ad make the site online again.

Comment: thank you for replay . my app is ASP.NET web from . i dont say any thing about MVC!